# One img aligned on the left, and one on the center, both vertically aligned, inside same div

Tags: html, css

I am struggling aligning 2 imgs in the same div. I want one to be aligned on the left, and the other to be in the center. Any suggestion?

Comment: Please show what you've tried and what specifically goes wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
div {
    background: red;
    text-align: center;
}
div img{
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.left {
   float:left;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="//placehold.it/50x50" class="left" />
    <img src="//placehold.it/50x50" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
  text-align: center;
  background: red;
}
.left {
  float: left;
}
.center {
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img class="left" src="http://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/images/facebook-icon(3).png">
  <img class="center" src="http://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/images/facebook-icon(3).png">
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7g6pu8hm/)

Comment: Why aren't the two images vertically aligned? I mean, why aren't they both in vertical center of the div? And, can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
.left {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" class="left">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its easy, just specify your div , and maybe give it a class

```
<div class="mydiv">
 <img src="(your-image)" width="(size)"        height="(size)" class="leftAlign">
  <img src="(your second image)" width="(size)" height="(size)" class="centerAlign" >
 </div>
```

And here is a stylesheet for alignment

```
  .mydiv{
width:100%;  
}
 .leftAlign{
position:absolute;
top:20px;
left:0px;
}
  .centerAlign{
position:absolute;
top:20px;
left:0;
right:0;
margin:auto;
}
```

This might work out for you.
I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, bpeterson76, your code does not center the .center.
Check this out:

```
div {
  position: relative;
}
.left {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
.center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
 -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
 -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
 -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4h8g9prb/

It works perfect, the only downside is browser support IE9 or later.